# Why does this code give a warning?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_TYPE
#define MEM_SIZE_BYTES  4096
#define MEM_SIZE_WORDS  MEM_SIZE_BYTES/sizeof(int)

int main() {

    printf("bytes are %d\n", MEM_SIZE_BYTES);
    printf("words are %d\n", MEM_SIZE_WORDS);

}
```

Compilation gives a warning...why?

```
testintsize.c:11:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
```

I found out SIZE_TYPE macro here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Type-Layout.html
Is that related to this.

Doing this did not cause the warning to go away:

```
#define SIZE_TYPE int
```

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns a value of type `size_t`, which has to be unsigned and big enough to fit all possible sizes on the platform, and on your specific platform is `unsigned long int` for which you need the `"%lu"` format. See e.g [this `printf` reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: What does SIZE_TYPE macro do ?

Comment: The compiler probably checks for it for the definition of `size_t`. Defining it could cause weird things to happen.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please surround any macro that's an expression more complex than a single number or identifier with parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several different ways to resolve this warning:

**Option #1:**

```
#define MEM_SIZE_WORDS MEM_SIZE_BYTES/sizeof(int)      // change this
#define MEM_SIZE_WORDS MEM_SIZE_BYTES/(int)sizeof(int) // to this
```

**Option #2:**

```
#define MEM_SIZE_WORDS MEM_SIZE_BYTES/sizeof(int)        // change this
#define MEM_SIZE_WORDS (int)(MEM_SIZE_BYTES/sizeof(int)) // to this
```

**Option #3:**

```
printf("words are %d\n", MEM_SIZE_WORDS);  // change this
printf("words are %lu\n", MEM_SIZE_WORDS); // to this
```

Comment: -1, this isn't an answer to the question, and in addition gives the wrong solution.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Read the question, you nitpicker. OP understands the problem, and is (was) just looking for a solution.

Comment: The real solution that is foreseen by the C standard is to use `%zu` as format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, sizeof returns an long unsigned int. One way to get around the warning:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_TYPE
#define MEM_SIZE_BYTES  4096
int intSize = sizeof(int);
#define MEM_SIZE_WORDS  MEM_SIZE_BYTES/intSize

int main() {

    printf("bytes are %d\n", MEM_SIZE_BYTES);
    printf("words are %d\n", MEM_SIZE_WORDS);

}
```

intSize is **global** variable. In some cases, it will not be considered as a best practice. Using a **cast to int will be superior** (see barak's comment and answer).

Comment: This will yield a runtime calculation every time you use `MEM_SIZE_WORDS`.

Comment: What is `#define SIZE_TYPE` macro doing here ?

Comment: Hi @barak, it's been ages since I wrote my last C code. Isn't that the case where MEM_SIZE_BYTES/intSize will be calculated once before compilation by the preprocessor? At that point, MEM_SIZE_WORDS will be simply replaced by the resulting value. That is, no recalculation at runtime.

Comment: `intSize` is a variable, the **preprocessor** does not handle variables in C. In c++, if you declare it as `const`, then the **compiler** might replace it with the value of that variable, and then ultimately replace the entire expression with a constant value.

Comment: @barak, thanks for the refresher. So, how the code will look like after the preprocessor is done? Will MEM_SIZE_WORDS be replaced with a 4096/intSize?

Comment: I believe so, yes. You can always view the dis-assembly if you want to be sure.

Comment: -1, this is not an anwer to the question, and gives not a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator returns type `size_t` which is an unsigned integer type. By C's implicit type conversion rules `MEM_SIZE_BYTES/sizeof(int)` also has the same type, `size_t`.

To print a value of that type use `%zu` as a `printf` format.